# Get value from a JSON file with multi dimensional array using jQuery $.getJSON method

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I've been trying to fetch some values from a JSON file using the $.getJSON method. The first two loops are static so I wrote the below code to fetch the value of "layers.name". From the third loop, the data in the layers may or may not be available. How can I fetch the value of all "layers.name"presented in the JSON file

PS: The JSON file is an output generated from a software where the layer is presented 
in this format
[image]

Here the code I've worked so far where I get the first two loop layers.

Html

```
<body>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="test.js"></script>
</body>
```

Javscript

```
$.getJSON('https://api.myjson.com/bins/6atbz', function(data) {
      var layer = data.layers.reverse()
      for (i=0; i<layer.length; i ++){
        name = data.layers[i].name
        id= data.layers[i].do_objectID
        var className = '.'+id
        var main = "<div class=\""+id+"\" data-number=\""+i+"\">"+name+"<\/div>"
        $('body').append(main);
        var subLayer = data.layers[i].layers.reverse()
        for(j=0; j<subLayer.length; j++){
          newname = data.layers[i].layers[j].name
          $().append(' '+newname);
          var subsubLayer = data.layers[i].layers[j]
          var sub = "<div class=\""+newname+"\" data-number=\""+j+"\">"+newname+"<\/div>"

          $(className).append(sub);
        }

      }

})
```

Thanks

[Link to Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/38b3m8ng/)

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to show a sample of the actual JSON string rather than a picture of what the JSON represents?

Comment: Link to the json file https://api.myjson.com/bins/6atbz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's a good idea use recursion. Here is example:

```
var container = document.getElementById("container");

$.getJSON('https://api.myjson.com/bins/6atbz', function(data) {
  buildTree(data, container)
})

function buildTree (node, container) {
  var layers = node.layers || [];
  console.info(node);

  layers.forEach(function(item) {
    var newContainer = document.createElement('div');
    var span = document.createElement('span');
    span.innerHTML = item.name;
    newContainer.appendChild(span);

    container.appendChild(newContainer);
    if(item.layers){
      buildTree(item, newContainer)
    }
  });
}
```

Here is live [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/ULw391W9BNm20vCXRLfL?p=preview)